# Pandas For Loop error - with and/if statements embedded

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series `pandas.DataFrame`, 'ES_Summary_Index1', as follows:

```
     Ticker_x                Date  Close_x 15M_Long 1H_Long Net_Long
0       ES H7 2016-10-18 13:44:59  2128.00        N     NaN         
1       ES H7 2016-10-18 13:59:59  2128.75        N     NaN         
2       ES H7 2016-10-18 14:14:59  2125.75        N     NaN         
3       ES H7 2016-10-18 14:29:59  2126.50        N       N         
4       ES H7 2016-10-18 14:44:59  2126.50        N     NaN         
5       ES H7 2016-10-18 16:14:59  2126.00        N     NaN         
6       ES H7 2016-10-18 16:44:59  2126.25        N     NaN         
7       ES H7 2016-10-18 17:59:59  2126.50        N     NaN         
8       ES H7 2016-10-18 18:14:59  2127.00        N     NaN         
9       ES H7 2016-10-18 19:14:59  2127.75        N     NaN         
10      ES H7 2016-10-18 19:44:59  2127.75        N     NaN         
11      ES H7 2016-10-18 19:59:59  2127.75        N     NaN         
12      ES H7 2016-10-18 20:44:59  2129.00        N     NaN         
13      ES H7 2016-10-18 21:29:59  2128.75        N       N         
14      ES H7 2016-10-18 21:44:59  2129.00        N     NaN
```

Focusing on the `15M_Long` and `1H_Long` columns, if both say 'Y' I want the `Net_Long` column to say `Long` also. If only one or neither say 'Y' then I want the `Net_Long` column to remain blank or say "N" (Whichever).

First, I set Net_Long column to blank:

```
ES_Summary_Index1['Net_Long'] = ''
```

Next, I'm writing a for loop statement to fill the `Net_Long` column:

```
for index, row in ES_Summary_Index1.iterrows():
    if ES_Summary_Index1.loc[index, '15M_Long'] is 'Y' & ES_Summary_Index1.loc[index, '1H_Long'] is 'Y':
        ES_Summary_Index1.loc['Net_Long'] = 'Long'
    else:
        ES_Summary_Index1.loc['Net_Long'] = 'N'
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'float'
```

...referring to the if statement above (if ES_Summary_Index1...). I've tried change from `&` to `and` but that doesn't fill the `Net_Long` column as I'd like. I've also tried `==` rather than is and that doesn't work. Can anyone assist?

Comment: `iterrows` solution is very slow, please check another solution with `numpy.where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to getting the correct logical test, inside your loop you should access the row directly.  Your current code resets the entire column every time through the loop:

**Code:**

```
df['Net_Long'] = ''

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['15M_Long'] is 'Y' and row['1H_Long'] is 'Y':
        row['Net_Long'] = 'Long'
    else:
        row['Net_Long'] = 'N'
```

**Test Data:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [x.strip().split() for x in """
    Ticker_x             Date  Close_x 15M_Long 1H_Long
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T13:44:59  2128.00        N     NaN
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T13:59:59  2128.75        N     NaN
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T19:59:59  2127.75        Y     NaN
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T20:44:59  2129.00        N       Y
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T21:29:59  2128.75        Y       Y
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T21:44:59  2129.00        N     NaN
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

**Produces:**

```
  Ticker_x                 Date  Close_x 15M_Long 1H_Long Net_Long
0    ES_H7  2016-10-18T13:44:59  2128.00        N     NaN        N
1    ES_H7  2016-10-18T13:59:59  2128.75        N     NaN        N
2    ES_H7  2016-10-18T19:59:59  2127.75        Y     NaN        N
3    ES_H7  2016-10-18T20:44:59  2129.00        N       Y        N
4    ES_H7  2016-10-18T21:29:59  2128.75        Y       Y     Long
5    ES_H7  2016-10-18T21:44:59  2129.00        N     NaN        N
```

Answer (score 3):

You need very fast vectorize [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with boolean mask:

```
mask = (df['15M_Long'] == 'Y') & (df['1H_Long'] == 'Y')
df['Net_Long'] = np.where(mask, 'Long', 'N')

print (df)
  Ticker_x                 Date  Close_x 15M_Long 1H_Long Net_Long
0    ES_H7  2016-10-18T13:44:59  2128.00        N     NaN        N
1    ES_H7  2016-10-18T13:59:59  2128.75        N     NaN        N
2    ES_H7  2016-10-18T19:59:59  2127.75        Y     NaN        N
3    ES_H7  2016-10-18T20:44:59  2129.00        N       Y        N
4    ES_H7  2016-10-18T21:29:59  2128.75        Y       Y     Long
5    ES_H7  2016-10-18T21:44:59  2129.00        N     NaN        N
```

**Timings**:

```
#length of df is 600 rows
In [183]: %timeit (iterate(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 67.1 ms per loop

In [184]: %timeit (vectorize(df1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop

#length of df is 6000 rows
In [177]: %timeit (iterate(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 681 ms per loop

In [178]: %timeit (vectorize(df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.23 ms per loop

#length of df is 60000 rows 
In [180]: %timeit (iterate(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 6.87 s per loop

In [181]: %timeit (vectorize(df1))
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
data = [x.strip().split() for x in """
    Ticker_x             Date  Close_x 15M_Long 1H_Long
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T13:44:59  2128.00        N     NaN
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T13:59:59  2128.75        N     NaN
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T19:59:59  2127.75        Y     NaN
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T20:44:59  2129.00        N       Y
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T21:29:59  2128.75        Y       Y
    ES_H7 2016-10-18T21:44:59  2129.00        N     NaN
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:], columns=data[0])
#for 600 rows * 100, 6000 rows *1000, 60k * 10000
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
df1 = df.copy()

def vectorize(df):
    mask = (df['15M_Long'] == 'Y') & (df['1H_Long'] == 'Y')
    df['Net_Long'] = np.where(mask, 'Long', 'N')
    return (df)

def iterate(df):
    df['Net_Long'] = ''

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['15M_Long'] is 'Y' and row['1H_Long'] is 'Y':
            row['Net_Long'] = 'Long'
        else:
            row['Net_Long'] = 'N'
    return df

print (iterate(df)) 
print (vectorize(df1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the following line:

```
if ES_Summary_Index1.loc[index, '15M_Long'] is 'Y' & ES_Summary_Index1.loc[index, '1H_Long'] is 'Y':
```

with

```
if ES_Summary_Index1.loc[index, '15M_Long']=='Y' and ES_Summary_Index1.loc[index, '1H_Long']=='Y':
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll accept the answer when I can in a few minutes!